# Predicting with GAM (mgcv) and categorical/factor covariate in R

Tags: r, predictive-models, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, marginal-effect

I have some data for multiple users and I want to generate some marginal effects for each user using GAM modelling. **If I do this exercise for just a single user (John)** as:

`model_1 = mgcv::gam(y ~ s(speed) + s(length) + s(price), data1)` with `data1` having data only for John, then I can get the *speed-effect* with `prediction_1 = mgcv::predict.gam(model_1, test_set, type="response")` where `test_set` is a table with `speed` as sequence `seq(0,100,by=5)` , while both `length` and `price` are fixed at John's mean values. It is the same as running `plot(ggeffects::ggpredict(model_1), facets = TRUE)` .

Now, I want to repeat this exercise for John but with a model that includes **all my users**. Hence, I am having a categorical/factor variable `user_id` and run the following model:

`model_2 = mgcv::gam(y ~ user_id + s(speed) + s(length) + s(price), data2)` with `data2` having all users' data. Now, If I want to obtain again only John's *speed-effect* but with `model_2` , I am trying `predictions_2 = mgcv::predict.gam(model_2, test_set2, type="response")` where `test_set2` only having `test_set2$user_id="John"` , again `speed` as a (0-100) sequence and both `length` and `price` fixed at John's mean values.

The results from these two exercises, although I was expecting to be the same, are different. I have also tried `test_set2` with `length` and `price` fixed at all users' mean values but again I can not get identical results for John as with `prediction_1`.

Could you please help me understand what I am doing wrong or missing here? How can I obtain `prediction_1` results using the model with the categorical? Much appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand why you would expect the same results. You probably should read this paper: https://peerj.com/articles/6876/ (in particular section "What do we mean by hierarchical smoothers?")

Comment: First off, your formatting here is difficult to read. I would edit your question to simply have all of your function as one code string / script and then explaining after the fact what your reasoning was for using this code. Second, I think you need to provide more information about 1) what you want your end result to be and 2) why you have chosen to take the steps you have so far.

Comment: @Roland , very intresting paper. So the suggestion here is to use interaction terms between `user_id` and the rest predictors like: `gam(y ~ user_id + s(speed, by=user_id) + s(length, by=user_id) + s(price, by=user_id), data2)`  and then try to extract the marginal effects for each user, right?

Comment: Possibly. Without background knowledge and access to the paper I can't recommend a specific model.

Comment: @Roland (not that I expect you to read it just to answer a question) that paper is open access

Comment: @GavinSimpson Sorry, that was a Freudian typo. I meant to write "data". I have actually read the paper and it is excellent. It's recommended reading material when I'm teaching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to model individual-specific effects (separate smooth effects for individuals), then you have to include terms in the model for each user.

In your example, all you did was introduce a different mean (constant) for each person. All individuals shared the same smooth effects of `speed` and `length`.

The HGAM paper mentioned by @Roland in the comments discusses modelling options for group and individual level effects. You basically have two options:

1. Do you want a common, shared effect, plus separate smooths for each individual, or
2. Only separate smooths for each individual

The end result should be similar in terms of fit, but differ in terms of how they decompose the effects. Which you use will depend on your questions and the specific nature of the system you are studying.

Within those options, you have 2 further choices. Do you want

1. random smooths for the individual effects, or
2. factor-by smooths for the individual effects

The smooths in Option 1 would all share the same wiggliness, while the smooths in Option 2 would be able to have different wigglinesses if support by the data.

Since we wrote that paper, mgcv has gained other ways to specify the Option 2 smooths.

If you want to just estimate a separate smooth for each individual, then you can use:

```r
gam(y ~ user_id + s(speed, by = user_id) +
                  s(length, by = user_id) +
                  s(price, by = user_id),
    data1, method = "REML")
```

whereas, if you have many individuals and expect the smooths to have different shapes but largely the same degree of wiggliness, you could fit

```r
gam(y ~ s(speed, user_id, bs = "fs") +
        s(length, user_id, bs = "fs") +
        s(price, user_id, bs = "fs"),
    data1, method = "REML")
```